# gradle Test tasks colliding with each other

Tags: testing, gradle

I have a [gradle project](https://github.com/idosu/questions/tree/master/gradle-double-Test-tasks) with 2 Test tasks, test and test2.

When running `gradle test test2` 2 times both `test` and `test2` ran again even though they should be `UP-TO-DATE`(when running `gradle test` It stays `UP-TO-DATE` no matter how many times I ran it).

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to recreate this error on another computer I found out that.

This error occurred on `gradle 2`,  on `gradle 3` It was OK.

This must have something to do with [this link](https://docs.gradle.org/3.0/release-notes#unique-default-test-result-and-report-directories-for-test-tasks)

### What I think is happening

It seems that on `gralde 2` the test results where exported to `$buildDir/test-results` and then the `UP-TO-DATE` function wouldn't work because the second Test tasks changed the output directory, which gives this directory structure:

```
build
    test-results
        binary
            test/...
            test2/...
        TEST-MyTest1.xml
        TEST-MyTest2.xml
```

And on `gradle 3` the results are exported to `$buildDir/test-results/$taskName`, which gives this directory structure:

```
build
    test-results
        test
            binary/...
            TEST-MyTest1.xml
        test2
            binary/...
            TEST-MyTest2.xml
```

P.S. If I am wrong please let me know